# Search input element needs transparent background color, and tag anchor misaligned

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

The search `<input>` element appears not have any `background-color` property set to it. This, at least in Firefox 3.6 on Ubuntu, causes the input element to default to a white background, which is quite ugly:

[image]

Setting the background color to transparent fixes this. Also, the tag anchor appears to be misaligned relative to the multiplier that appears next to it on the user tags pages, as well as the recent tag list on the homepage:

[image]

Setting `vertical-align: top` on the tag anchor seems to fix this.

Comment: thanks @YiJiang, we're looking into this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As usual, `/blame @balpha`.

Fixed now, thanks!